How do I stop my AWS Security Group being invalid?
I'm trying to create an AWS RDS instance that's connected to by an EC2 instance. I have two security groups and one RDS instance, which I'm creating using Cloud Formation. You can see my .yaml file below:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: template v2
Resources:
  MyEC2Instance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-05d929ac8893c382f
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup

  MyDBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: mydbinstance
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
      Engine: mariadb
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: password
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DatabaseSecurityGroup
      PubliclyAccessible: false

  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Enable access from the public internet."
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  DatabaseSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Enable access from the EC2 instance."
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId

  MyDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "Subnet group for RDS instance"
      SubnetIds:
        - subnet-2
        - subnet-1

I've validated this template in the application composer and get no errors. But when I try and create the stack I get the following error:
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid security group , groupId= test-9-databasesecuritygroup-4rosfigqstws, groupName=. (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ...)

I've looked around online and heard it could be subnets. So, I've tried adding subnets attached to my local VPC, but that hasn't fixed the issue. How do I resolve this?  Is it still a problem with subnets, or is there something wrong with my security group?

A 400 error means Access Denied. Can you check that the user running CloudFormation has permission to create a Security Group?

@JohnRotenstein Yes, they have permission. I'm running CloudFormation on an admin account. The error doesn't come up in the security group creation, that completes fine. It comes up in RDS instance creation. I take it from your comment it doesn't look like there's an issue with the template?

Try changing !GetAtt InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId to !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup.

It was actually the DatabaseSecurity group one! It needed to be !GetAtt InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId

The issue is in the MyDBInstance. I had a reference to the Database security group: !Ref DatabaseSecurityGroup. But this returns the name of the group, not the ID, which is what's required.
To fix this I changed the instance from:
MyDBInstance:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    DBInstanceIdentifier: mydbinstance
    AllocatedStorage: 20
    DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
    Engine: mariadb
    MasterUsername: admin
    MasterUserPassword: password
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !Ref DatabaseSecurityGroup
    PubliclyAccessible: false

To:
MyDBInstance:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    DBInstanceIdentifier: mydbinstance
    AllocatedStorage: 20
    DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
    Engine: mariadb
    MasterUsername: admin
    MasterUserPassword: password
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt DatabaseSecurityGroup.GroupId
    PubliclyAccessible: false

After this change the stack built correctly.
